# "Like Button" Spring Boot Java Web App On Click Update database

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, spring-boot

I want to be able click the like button on my page and have it go back, run some java checks and modify database if needed, and current page

Whats best way at doing this in my situation?

I have a Spring Boot Maven Java Web App. The home page uses a @Controller and Model Attributes to pass data to home page.

Here is basic Java Controller Method Class

```
package controller;

import model.HomeModel;
import java.net.URI;
**import all the rest of things I need**

@Controller
public class HomeController {


@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String home(Model model) {

    //Method Variables
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    String sql = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    StringBuffer sb = null;
    String content_category = null;
    String content_header = null;
    String content_text = null;
    String recent = null;
    String content_date = null;
    String content_time = null;
    String content_posted = null;
            etc
            etc
            etc
            etc
            etc


    // Get Body Deatils
    try {
        connection = getConnection();
        stmt = connection.createStatement();

        sql =   "My PostreSQL string to get all my data";

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (rs.next()) {
            content_username = rs.getString("user_name");
            etc
            etc
            etc
            etc
            etc
            etc

            content_rating_status = rs.getBoolean("rating_status");
        }
        stmt.close();
        connection.close();
    }catch(Exception e) {return e.toString();}


    model.addAttribute("content_header", content_header);
    model.addAttribute("content_category", content_category);
    model.addAttribute("content_username", content_username);
    model.addAttribute("content_choice_text", content_choice_text);
    model.addAttribute("content_date", content_date);
    model.addAttribute("content_time", content_time);
    model.addAttribute("content_modified", content_modified);
    **model.addAttribute all the rest of the things ill be using**

    return "home";
}
```

/*Database Connection*/
    private static Connection getConnection() throws URISyntaxException, SQLException {
Bla Bla Bla Connetion method
    }
}

My home page mapped to ("/") from controller above

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>The Arsenal Review</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/thymeleaf-demo.css" th:href="@{../assets/css/style.css}" />
    <script src="../assets/js/8005dfa397.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script>$(window).load(function() {$(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");;});</script>
</head>
<body background = "../assets/img/stadium.jpg">
<div class="se-pre-con" background = "../assets/img/preloader_7.gif"></div>
<div class="container">
<div class = "container">

    <div class = "headContainer">
        <div class = "navIconContainer">
            <div class = "navIcon">
                <i class="fa  fa-navicon"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "logoContainer">
            <img src = "../assets/img/logo.png"/>
        </div>
        <div class = "nextGameContainer">
            <div class = "nextGame">Arsenal vs <span th:text="${match_opponent}"></span>  <span th:text="${match_date}"></span> <span th:text="${match_time}"></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class = "randomIconContainer">
            <div class = "randomIcon">
                <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "bodyContainer">
        <div class = "header">
                <span th:text="${content_header}"></span>
        </div>
        <div class = "categoryType">
        <span th:text="${content_category}"></span>
        </div>
        <div class = "author">
        <span th:text="${content_username}"></span>
        </div>
        <div class = "date">
        Posted : <span th:text="${content_choice_text}"></span> <span th:text="${content_date}"></span> <span th:text="${content_time}"></span>
        </div>
        <div class = "content">
        <p th:text="${content_text}"></p>
                <span class = "modified" th:text="${content_Modified}"></span>
        </div>
        <div class = "socialContainer">
                    <div class = "itemContainer">
                        Share <i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i>
                        <span th:text="${content_shares}"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "itemContainer">
                        <span th:utext="${content_rating}"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "itemContainer">
                        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
                        <span th:text="${content_likes}"></span>                        
                    </div>
                    <div class = "itemContainer">
                        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
                        <span th:text="${content_comments}"></span>                     
                    </div>
                    <div class = "itemContainer">
                        <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                        <span th:text="${content_views}"></span>    
                    </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "comments">
            <div class = "parentComment">Parent CommentS</div>
            <div class = "childComment">Child Comments</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "footerContainer">
        <div class = "footerElement1">Footer Element 1</div>
        <div class = "footerElement2">Footer Element 2</div>
        <div class = "footerElement3">Footer Element 3</div>
        <div class = "footerElement4">Footer Element 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the actual question? Does the code you presented work? Is it missing anything? Does it fail? If so, how? Etc., etc.

Comment: Ok ill write question better. Just need a hour